# Automatic table and data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I must create a report in Winforms DevExpress xtraReport. Report will contain dynamically created table. I want to get something like this:

[image]

So I have list of object with data  person = John, article = juice, quantity = 2; person = John, article = meat, quantity = 3.

In addition I want to empty article doesn't appear (in my example shouldn't be column meat).

How can I achieve this in easiest way? Is there any other way than manually create each row? I've tried using Pivot but it seems hard to achieve without much work.

Comment: oh, and it means that columns will be dynamcally created so I cant just bind data

Comment: use [Pivot Grid](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4030)

Comment: @IvanStoevYes, i tried this approach, but question is: How to bind data when my collumns are dynamically created? I cant have object to bind data, because i cant know field names

Comment: RowField=person, ColumnField=article, DataField=quantity

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataTable as a data source instead if you don't know the fields at runtime.